# How should I type hint UserModel in a Laravel package?

Tags: laravel, model, namespaces, type-hinting

I want to type hint the User model in a package. By default, it's `App\User`. In a channel class, this would be ok:

```
class ChannelExample
{
    public function join(\App\User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If the App namespace has been changed (using `artisan app:name` for instance), it will no more work.

In a package, obviously, it's not possible to know what namespace users will use. Therefore, typehinting is not a good idea...

What is the best practice to type hint and keep the package work with any App namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `Contract` that laravel uses for it's `Auth` Classes.

```
public function join(Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Completely forgot about the contract! Thanks

Comment: @Arcesilas you're welcome. care to set it as the answer ?

Comment: Had to wait a few minutes before I was able to do it